# Why the last value indexing in tuple or list give different class and slicing give different in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, tuples, slice

For e.g.
if

```
a=(1,[2,3])
```

Then indexing

```
b=a[1]
```

will give class **list** *(because index value is list)*

`[2, 3] <class 'list'>`

but while slicing

```
c=a[1:]
```

give the class **tuple**

`([2, 3],) <class 'tuple'>`

Can anyone explain why this is so?
How does Python differentiate indexing from slicing in regards to determining class?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `c=a[1:]` returns a portion of the tuple no matter what is contained. It would be a mess if slices returned the underlying object type when you slice a sequence!

Answer (score 3):

Indexing gives you a specific item within the sequence, while slicing returns a segment thereof, even if that segment is one element long.

Comment: But how is it affecting class?

Comment: Because a[1:] is a tuple with one element (which happens to be a list). When you indexed you were given the element alone. I suggest experimenting with different data types inside the tuple.

@wwii: thanks, I knew something was off with my wording. :)

Answer (score 0):

A tuple consists of a number of arbitrary objects/heterogeneous items which support indexing and slicing operations.

The following will always give you a tuple:

```
t = tuple()

t[start:stop]
t[start:]
t[:stop]
t[:]
```

If you'll use **indices** to access objects in `tuple` like `t[0]` or `t[-1]` then the type will be different for different indices depending on what is present on that specific index.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing returns a slice of a sequence (i.e. the same type), while indexing returns the item at that index. Compare:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3]
>>> t[1:]  # Slice -> list
[2, 3]
>>> t[1]  # Index -> int
2
```